# "I would not prefer to" or "I would prefer not to"?

Tags: expressions, american-english

(1) Is there any difference/nuance (in mood, meaning, or something else) between "I would not prefer to" or "I would prefer not to"?

(2) Which is the more/most common in usage?

Comment: "I would not prefer to" is bit informal or colloquial, the more formal language is to use the other way around.

Comment: Ask [Bartleby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartleby,_the_Scrivener).

Comment: Both are valid, but they mean different things.

Answer (score 1):

"Prefer not to" is far more common (over 2100 instances in GloWbE, against 157 of "not/n't prefer to".

I was going to say that there is a difference in nuance, that "not prefer to" means that the person has no preference, as opposed to a preference for the negative. But when I look at the examples of "not prefer to", I find that, apart from a small number of questions like "Do you not prefer to XXX?", they are nearly all cases where I would expect "prefer not to" - there are very few where they seem to be saying "do(es) not have a preference for".

So on that evidence I would say that "not prefer to" is a less common variant (and one that feels awkward to me) but as used, it does not usually have a different meaning from "prefer not to".

Comment: Consider a situation where person P equally (and 'positively') desires to do two activities, A and B. Then P could say they "do not prefer to do A" (the comparison with B is implicit), but it would not be consistent with P's desires to say that they "prefer not to do A".

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But as I say, observation of the examples in GloWbE shows that people don't generally make that distinction, and often use "don't prefer to" to mean that they prefer not to. I assume that in that case most people would say that they "have no preference". Language means what people use and understand it to mean, not what somebody thinks it ought to mean.

Comment: I agree that if we look at pragmatic usage rather than pure logic, the two things effectively mean the same.

Comment: "Pragmatic usage" is overwhelmingly what we mean by "mean". We speak language, not logic, and the fact that a logical analysis might give a different answer is of little interest or relevance to most people. However "I could care less" arose (probably by irony), if many people use it to mean "I couldn't care less", then that is what it means.